# React-rails: Component with { prerender: true } in options hash gives a V8:Error - Unexpected token <

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, v8, reactjs, execjs

I'm using the [`react-rails`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) gem in a project.

Whenever I pass in the `prerender: true` option to the options hash of the `react_component` helper method, I get the error: `V8::Error - Unexpected token <`. My component works fine when I remove `prerender: true` from the options hash.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'react-rails', github: 'reactjs/react-rails'
```

The view:

```
= react_component("AssignmentWindowProgressBar", { assignment: @assignment_json }, { prerender: true })
```

Coffee file:

```
###* @jsx React.DOM ###

@AssignmentWindowProgressBar = React.createClass
  render: ->
    `<div>Hi world.</div>`

# this is located in this file:
# ./apps/assets/javascripts/components/assignments/AssignmentWindows.js.jsx.coffee
```

Stack trace:

```
V8::Error - Unexpected token < at <eval>:19037:15:
  therubyracer (0.12.1) lib/v8/error.rb:86:in `block in try'
  therubyracer (0.12.1) lib/v8/error.rb:83:in `try'
  therubyracer (0.12.1) lib/v8/context.rb:95:in `block in eval'
  therubyracer (0.12.1) lib/v8/context.rb:248:in `block (2 levels) in lock_scope_and_enter'
  therubyracer (0.12.1) lib/v8/context.rb:245:in `block in lock_scope_and_enter'
  therubyracer (0.12.1) lib/v8/context.rb:244:in `lock_scope_and_enter'
  therubyracer (0.12.1) lib/v8/context.rb:204:in `enter'
  therubyracer (0.12.1) lib/v8/context.rb:94:in `eval'
  execjs (2.2.0) lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:11:in `block in initialize'
  execjs (2.2.0) lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:78:in `block in lock'
  execjs (2.2.0) lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:76:in `lock'
  execjs (2.2.0) lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:9:in `initialize'
  execjs (2.2.0) lib/execjs/runtime.rb:44:in `compile'
  execjs (2.2.0) lib/execjs/module.rb:27:in `compile'
  ... end of execjs errors ...
```

Thanks for any and all help guys!

Comment: Afraid I don't use coffee... or ruby for that matter. But I can tell you that the issue is because whatever you're using to compile the coffee's jsx -> standard coffee isn't working.  Perhaps you need something like this: https://github.com/KyleAMathews/coffee-react-quickstart

Comment: The rails assets pipeline will first compile it from coffee to jsx. The backticks tell coffee to simply ignore whatever is encased in backticks and pass it to javascript. In this case, the coffeescript is passing it to the jsx transformer. I think it's not getting passed through the jsx transformer when it's being rendered serverside.

http://coffeescript.org/#embedded

Comment: Looks like we have a test running the server generated stuff that uses coffeescript, so it *should* be working. I haven't been working on this, but it looks like we expect a `components.js` file which we load for server rendering. I assume you're doing that, but maybe we have a bug about when we load that file into the VM?

Comment: Hi Paul. My `components.js.coffee` file is located in the `app/assets/javascripts/` dir. It simply has this line: `#= require_tree ./components`

Comment: that file shouldn't be coffee... just js

Comment: You might want to try using https://github.com/jsdf/coffee-react-transform as that's a *cleaner* solution than using backticks IMO. I've been using it actively for over a month now with great success.

Comment: Thanks @KyleMathews, I'll have to take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Copied answer from https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails#jsx

> To transform your JSX into JS, simply create .js.jsx files. These
>   files will be transformed on request, or precompiled as part of the
>   assets:precompile task.
>
> CoffeeScript files can also be used, by creating .js.jsx.coffee files.
>   We also need to embed JSX inside backticks so CoffeeScript ignores the
>   syntax it doesn't understand. Here's an example:

```
Component = React.createClass
  render: ->
    `<ExampleComponent videos={this.props.videos} />`
```

Notice file extension.